# Cannot resolve symbol Configuration when initializing Parse

Tags: android, parse-platform, initialization

Im trying to initializing Parse on the oncreate function but
it cant find the static class Configuration.

here's the initialization from documentation:

```
    Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(this)
            .applicationId("myAppId") 
            .clientKey(null) 
            .addNetworkInterceptor(new ParseLogInterceptor())
            .enableLocalDataStore()
            .server("https://myapp.herokuapp.com/parse/").build());
```

The Configuration in Parse.Configuration is marked red.

I have also added the latest dependency:

```
dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.13.0'
   compile 'com.parse:parseinterceptors:0.0.2' 
   compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
}
```

Not sure why it cant find the configuration class.

Answer (score 5):

Remove Parse lib files if you have any in your libs folder.

Add just this line to your gradle

```
compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.13.1'
```

than sync your gradle.

Comment: Thanks. My project had such this inside *libs* folder.